# How can I rearrange a pandas dataframe into this specific configuration?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I'm trying to rearrange a pandas dataframe that looks like this: [![enter image description here][1]][1]

into a dataframe that looks like this:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

This is derived in a way that for each original row, a number of rows are created where the first two columns are unchanged, the third column is which of the next original columns this new column is from, and the fourth column is the corresponding float value (e.g. 20.33333).

I don't think this is a pivot table, but I'm not sure how exactly to get this cleanly. Apologies if this question has been asked before, I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Apologies also if my explanation or formatting were less than ideal! Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you please post tables as text not as images as it makes it easier for others to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) if need counts values per 3 columns:

```
df1 = df.melt(id_vars=['CentroidID_O', 'CentroidID_D'], var_name='dt_15')
df2 = (df1.groupby(['CentroidID_O', 'CentroidID_D', 'dt_15'])
          .size()
          .reset_index(name='counts'))
```